# How do I set Akka ActorSystem name in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, akka

Currently, Akka ActorSystem in Play is named "play" (Play 2.3.5).

Is there a way to change Akka system name to something else ?

This is useful when configuring Akka cluster because it requires all nodes to use same system name.

Comment: @Ryan Are you able to work around "Trying to join member with wrong ActorSystem name, but was ignored" ? According to this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/XFmoSv6FNIs all nodes need to have same actor system name.

Comment: You can also see from Akka source code that different system names are not allowed: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-cluster/src/main/scala/akka/cluster/ClusterDaemon.scala#L400-L402

Comment: To answer my own question, looking at Play source, looks like there is no way to override actor system name: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/system/Invoker.scala#L19-L24

Answer (score 3):

in application.conf

`play.akka.actor-system = "newname"`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in Play 2.4, the name is configurable through

```
play.akka.config = "my-akka"
```

See details in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka